# Customizing JetPack Publicize Sharing

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I want to know how to setup the final code to add to my  theme Function.php file to let jetpack publicize share as this :

Post Title + Post link

Using this guide here :

https://lobby.vip.wordpress.com/wordpress-com-documentation/customizing-publicize-sharing-behavior/

I'm not familiar with filter/actions

Comment: Here's the documentation for background: [Plugin Basics: Hooks: Actions and Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#hooks-actions-and-filters)

Comment: yes i saw it but i need to just setup the above code so i can add it to my functions.php